# How to change shape of dots in dotted line.

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using C# and iTextSharp and have following code

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Some text here.");
        DottedLineSeparator dl = new DottedLineSeparator();
        dl.Offset = 17f;
        dl.Gap = 7f;
        dl.LineWidth = 3f;
        p.Add(dl);
        doc.Add(p);
```

It's working fine and I can see a dotted line but these dots are of circle shape.  Is there any way to change shape of these dots from circle to rectangle?

Comment: There is a type LINE_CAP_PROJECTING_SQUARE.  So see DottedLineSeparator : https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/74b3cf427b834714c71723383bdb5660edf3acc1/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/draw/DottedLineSeparator.cs.  Replace round with square.  Also see : https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/cb34723c6326bff723c49cd8a4286b62480a69f8/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfContentByte.cs

Comment: Problem is solved. thanks jdweng